# maxdrawdown function

Tags: r, finance

In R, I see there are two packages that have a maxdrawdown function.

One is **fTrading** and the other is **PerformaceAnalytics**.

Each of those does a different calculation.

1. fTrading seems to make the assumption that the values are prices of an asset so the drawdown is in valuation.
2. The same applies to PerformanceAnalytics except it gives the answer as a percentage.

Is there a package with a maxdrawdown function that expects P/L data in a series and gives the draw down based on that?

*e.g* if you had the following data

```
c(12,10,5,-4,-2,1,5,6)
```

The max drawdown would be :

```
-4 + -2=-6.
```

Comment: I usually use `maxdrawdown` from the [**tseries**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=tseries) package ...

Comment: the one from tseries is exactly the same as the one from fTrading

Comment: I was really just pointing out another package with a maxdrawdown function that you didn't mention.  `fTrading::maxDrawdown` is based on `tseries::maxdrawdown` (which is older).  The advantage to using `tseries` is that it doesn't Depend on several packages that you might not want to install and load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're  trying to find the `maxDrawDown` of the `cumsum` of PnL (which is the same as the account value).

```
> library(fTrading)
> maxDrawDown(cumsum(c(0, c(12,10,5,-4,-2,1,5,6))))
$maxdrawdown
[1] 6

$from
[1] 3

$to
[1] 5
```

Comment: To be exact, it should be `maxDrawDown(cumsum(0, pnl))` to account for the possibility that the max value at any point is `V(t=0) = 0`. It is more obvious if you test with `pnl <- c(-30, 30, 12,10,5,-4,-2,1,5,6)`

Answer (score 7):

It's easy to write your own function:

```
drawdown <- function(pnl) {
   cum.pnl  <- c(0, cumsum(pnl))
   drawdown <- cum.pnl - cummax(cum.pnl)
   return(tail(drawdown, -1))
}

maxdrawdown <- function(pnl)min(drawdown(pnl))
```

(Of course, you can change the sign and replace `min` by `max` if your convention is that drawdown should be a positive quantity)

```
pnl <- c(12,10,5,-4,-2,1,5,6)
drawdown(pnl)
# [1]  0  0  0 -4 -6 -5  0  0
maxdrawdown(pnl)
# [1] -6
```

Comment: how would you get it as a percentage?

Comment: You can get percentage values by "pnl / total_investment". Where, total_investment is your invested amount.

Comment: Could you please explain how the last line works? `maxdrawdown <- function(pnl)min(drawdown(pnl))`